# Splitting a graph legend into two legends

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

Im trying to split a single long legend into two legends. However, the way i did it just filled in the entire line. The is what im trying to achieve: (I think it would be better if those icons were just a 'x' or 'triangle' without a line through it.)

[image]

I tried adding a new legend with new rectangles and use fill command, but it would fill the line on the graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\hyphenation{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=left,
  ymin=0, ymax=210,
  ymajorgrids = true,
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=1},%
  symbolic x coords={R2G,Gaussian,Box,Sobel, Edge Total,SIFT Total},
    xtick distance=1,
    %nodes near coords,
    ymode=log,
    x tick label style = {font=\small, rotate=45, anchor=east},
  ylabel=Energy Consumption (nanoJoule/Operation),
]

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=west,rotate=60,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,blue]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,29)
    (Gaussian,59)
    (Box,64)
    (Sobel,127)
    (Edge Total,210)
    (SIFT Total,861)
}; \label{CPU}


\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=35,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,red]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,7)
    (Gaussian,10)
    (Box,12)
    (Sobel,21)
    (Edge Total,46)
    (SIFT Total,7)
}; \label{GPU}

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=35,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,black]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,20)
    (Gaussian,26)
    (Box,26)
    (Sobel,46)
    (Edge Total,20)
    (SIFT Total,91)
}; \label{FPGA}

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=35,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,orange]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,22)
    (Gaussian,36)
    (Box,33)
    (Sobel,49)
    (Edge Total,153)
    (SIFT Total,102)
}; \label{HLS}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  symbolic x coords={R2G,Gaussian,Box,Sobel, Edge Total,SIFT Total},
 xtick=data,
  %nodes near coords,
  ymin=0, ymax=25,
  ymode=log,
  ylabel=Throughput (Gops)
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=CPU}\addlegendentry{CPU}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=GPU}\addlegendentry{GPU}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=FPGA}\addlegendentry{FPGA}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=HLS}\addlegendentry{HLS}

\addplot [nodes near coords style={anchor=west,rotate=60,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,blue]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,0.35)
    (Gaussian,0.35)
    (Box,0.32)
    (Sobel,0.32)
    (Edge Total,0.12)
    (SIFT Total,0.34)
};\addlegendentry{CPU (T)}

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,red]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,1.48)
    (Gaussian,2.07)
    (Box,1.72)
    (Sobel,1.97)
    (Edge Total,24.88)
    (SIFT Total,1.57)
}; \addlegendentry{GPU (T)}

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,black]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,0.51)
    (Gaussian,0.79)
    (Box,0.79)
    (Sobel,0.90)
    (Edge Total,8.70)
    (SIFT Total,0.79)
}; \addlegendentry{FPGA (T)}


\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,orange]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,0.47)
    (Gaussian,0.57)
    (Box,0.62)
    (Sobel,0.84)
    (Edge Total,1.13)
    (SIFT Total,0.71)
}; \addlegendentry{HLS (T)}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `axis` environments, so you could add a different legend in each, specifying the styles of the legend entries manually. E.g. in the first `axis` add

```
\addlegendimage{mark=x, only marks} \addlegendentry{Energy}
\addlegendimage{mark=triangle, only marks} \addlegendentry{Throughput}
```

and set `legend pos=north west` in the `axis` options. In the second, add

```
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=CPU, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{CPU}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=GPU, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{GPU}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=FGPA, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{FPGA}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=HLS, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{HLS}
```

and use the `legend style` you already have for that one. (The `ultra thick` addition is optional of course, from your screenshot you seemed to want thicker lines in that legend.) This doesn't include any referencing for the markers. One method for fixing that is to define two new styles, e.g. `markA/.style={mark=x}`, and use that in both plots and legend.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\hyphenation{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=left,
  ymin=0, ymax=210,
  ymajorgrids = true,
  legend pos=north west,
  symbolic x coords={R2G,Gaussian,Box,Sobel, Edge Total,SIFT Total},
  xtick distance=1,
    %nodes near coords,
  ymode=log,
  x tick label style = {font=\small, rotate=45, anchor=east},
  ylabel=Energy Consumption (nanoJoule/Operation),
]

\addlegendimage{mark=x, only marks} \addlegendentry{Energy}
\addlegendimage{mark=triangle, only marks} \addlegendentry{Throughput}

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=west,rotate=60,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,blue]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,29)
    (Gaussian,59)
    (Box,64)
    (Sobel,127)
    (Edge Total,210)
    (SIFT Total,861)
}; \label{CPU}


\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=35,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,red]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,7)
    (Gaussian,10)
    (Box,12)
    (Sobel,21)
    (Edge Total,46)
    (SIFT Total,7)
}; \label{GPU}

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=35,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,black]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,20)
    (Gaussian,26)
    (Box,26)
    (Sobel,46)
    (Edge Total,20)
    (SIFT Total,91)
}; \label{FPGA}

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=35,inner xsep=5pt},smooth,mark=triangle,orange]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,22)
    (Gaussian,36)
    (Box,33)
    (Sobel,49)
    (Edge Total,153)
    (SIFT Total,102)
}; \label{HLS}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.22)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  symbolic x coords={R2G,Gaussian,Box,Sobel, Edge Total,SIFT Total},
 xtick=data,
  %nodes near coords,
  ymin=0, ymax=25,
  ymode=log,
  ylabel=Throughput (Gops)
]

\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=CPU, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{CPU}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=GPU, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{GPU}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=FGPA, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{FPGA}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=HLS, no markers, ultra thick}\addlegendentry{HLS}

\addplot [nodes near coords style={anchor=west,rotate=60,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,blue]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,0.35)
    (Gaussian,0.35)
    (Box,0.32)
    (Sobel,0.32)
    (Edge Total,0.12)
    (SIFT Total,0.34)
};

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,red]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,1.48)
    (Gaussian,2.07)
    (Box,1.72)
    (Sobel,1.97)
    (Edge Total,24.88)
    (SIFT Total,1.57)
};

\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,black]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,0.51)
    (Gaussian,0.79)
    (Box,0.79)
    (Sobel,0.90)
    (Edge Total,8.70)
    (SIFT Total,0.79)
};


\addplot[nodes near coords style={anchor=north,rotate=0,inner xsep=3pt},smooth,mark=x,orange]
  coordinates{
    (R2G,0.47)
    (Gaussian,0.57)
    (Box,0.62)
    (Sobel,0.84)
    (Edge Total,1.13)
    (SIFT Total,0.71)
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again Torbjørn T., Ah it seems that the method i tried was based of the bargraphs i did earlier. This is much simpler.